# Opening and closing a large number of files on python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program which organizes my school mark and for every subject I created a file.pck where are saved all the marks of that subject. Since I have to open and pickle.load 10+ files I decided to make 2 functions, files_open():

```
subj1 = open(subj1_file)
subj1_marks = pickle.load(subj1)
subj2 = open(subj2_file)
subj2marks = pickle.load(subj2)
```

and file_close():

```
subj1.close()
subj2.close()
```

The problem is that I had to make every variable in file_open() global and the function now is too long. I tried to avoid that problem by calling variables like:

```
file_open.subj1
```

but it does work and I can't understand why.

Comment: Can you post your functions and your code? It's hard to help you when we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: why do you leave the files open? can't you `open`, `pickle.load` & `close` at once?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have a bunch of similar values to which the same operations will be performed, they should all be in a single container of some sort (a list or dictionary, perhaps), rather than individual variables.  It's easy to iterate over the contents of a container, doing something to a bunch of variables can't be done except by repeating code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you just want to open, load and close the file afterwards I would suggest a simple helper function:

```
def load_marks(filename):
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:  # don't forget to open as binary
         marks = pickle.load(f)
    return marks
```

Use like this:

```
subj1_marks = load_marks(subj1_file)
```

The file is closed when going out of scope of `with` block, and your data remains accessible even if the file is closed which may be your (unjustified) concern with your question.

Note: someone suggested that what you really want (maybe) is to save all your data in one big pickle file.
In that case, you could create a dictionary containing your data:

```
d = dict()
d["mark1"] = subj1_marks
d["mark2"] = subj2_marks
...
```

and perform one sole `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()` on the dictionary (if data is picklable then a dictionary of this data is also picklable): that would be simpler to handle 1 big file than a lot of them, knowning that you need all of them anyway.

Comment: Don't you want to use `pickle.load(f)`?

Comment: Got caught not testing my code :) thanks. classical mistake.

Comment: I think the OP here needs some pointers to learning about Python dictionaries. Can you help  him?

Comment: @jsbueno I think I know what you mean. I edited my post accodingly.